# How to get only possible non overlapping blocks from images of any given size and show them in Python

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I have images of varying resolutions, and I would like to extract non-overlapping blocks from these images.

However, because the images have not fixed size and my block size is big (64x64), I would like to get only **non-overlapping blocks that could be found** in an image. If the block exceeds the image borders, I don't want to get them.

I tried the view_as_blocks function from scikit-image as below:

```
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks
for elem in listOfFiles:
    # Reading image
    print("Reading image "+elem)

    img = cv2.imread(elem)
    print(img.shape) #for example, one image is (2059, 2059, 3)

    Blocks = view_as_blocks(img, block_shape=(64, 64, 3))
```

The code returns the following error:

```
ValueError: 'block_shape' is not compatible with 'arr_in'
```

I also tried the Patch Extractor from scikit-learn, as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image
import cv2
import numpy 

for elem in listOfFiles:
    # Reading image
    print("Reading image "+elem)

    img = cv2.imread(elem)
    print(img.shape)

    pe = image.PatchExtractor(patch_size=(64,64))
    pe_fit = pe.fit(img)
    pe_trans = pe.transform(img)
    print('Patches shape: {}'.format(pe_trans.shape))
```

The error that returns to me is the following:

```
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

the function image.extract_patches_2d from sklearns **runs perfectly, but unfortunatelly it works only for overlapping blocks as you can see** [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12657).

These functions also don't help me because I also want to show the image **with these blocks selected**, so I also need another matrix with coordinates of such blocks **and show the selected blocks**.

Is that possible to that in Python?

Comment: Blocks are by default non overlapping, you just need to fix the block shape now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't care about the incomplete blocks at the edges, you can manually check the number of blocks along each dimension, and crop your image to that shape:

```py
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks


for elem in listOfFiles:
    # Reading image
    print("Reading image "+elem)

    img = cv2.imread(elem)
    print(img.shape) #for example, one image is (2059, 2059, 3)
    block_shape = np.array((64, 64, 3))
    nblocks = np.array(img.shape) // block_shape  # integer division
    crop_r, crop_c, crop_ch = nblocks * block_shape
    cropped_img = img[:crop_r, :crop_c, :crop_ch]
    Blocks = view_as_blocks(cropped_img, block_shape=(64, 64, 3))
```